# Search Engine Friendly urls in App Engine - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to create search engine friendly URL in my Google App Engine Java app.  Are there any examples demonstrating how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) by tuckey. It's a Java Web Filter for any J2EE compliant web application server (and App Engine), which allows you to rewrite URLs before they get to your code.

Usage:

Move the urlrewrite.xml to the /war/WEB-INF directory.

Move the urlrewrite-3.2*.jar to the /war/WEB-INF/lib directory.

Add this to your /war/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>  
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Add your configuration of your search engine friendly URLs to /war/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml

Redeploy your Google App.